# How to extend a System.Web.Services.WebService without a new class name?

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, asmx

I've tried to do this in several different forms and this is just the most recent. I usually bumble for several hours and never get anywhere so I'd like to put the question out here with my real-world example.

I have Web Services which I write XML from so that people can pull information from our server, so I have:

```
(namespace)
public static class WebServices
{
    public static void WriteXML(this WebService svc, DataSet results)
    {
        if (results != null)
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?><xsl:stylesheet version=\"1.0\" " +
                "xmlns:xsl=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">" + results.GetXml() + "</xsl:stylesheet>");
    }
}
```

Unforunately, that's only accessible doing:

```
using (namespace)
....
this.WriteXML(DataSet);
```

When I want

```
using (namespace)
....
WriteXML(DataSet);
```

What am I missing to do so?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just add the method to your `WebService` class?

Comment: Every web service class? Mostly because it's easier to add the using directive and it's less of a hassle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you wrote an extension method for `WebService` - your first parameter is `this WebService svc` which in turn means that your extension method `WriteXML` can only be called on an instance of `WebService` .

Comment: I understand why it's happening, I just don't know how to get to my goal and I'm so close :)

Comment: you can't get your goal because WebService is NOT a partial class... either the way you have it now OR a new classname which inherits from `WebService`.

Answer (score 0):

You could get away with being able to add a method if it were a partial class but in the MSDN docs it doesn't say it's partial. You have to extend it with extension methods and have to use the `this` keyword to access it. Five extra characters doesn't seem too bad to me. Is there another reason why you don't want to use the keyword?

Comment: Guess I'm just being an ingrate, seems silly to have to add it :/

Answer (score 0):

You can place that method into a base class, then derive all of your web services from the base class. The base class will derive from WebService.

BTW, unless you use the members of the `WebService` class, you don't need to derive from it at all. You can simply decorate your web service classes with `[WebService]`.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I was trying to get this in there with as little manual work as possible. Having to always inherit the derived class would annoy me, especially when I forget to and can't figure out what's wrong :)